# Search Text in a PDF file (Attachments)

Tags: attachment, pdf, encodingutil, content-search

I am not able to search text in a pdf file tied to attachments(Notes and Attachments) using apex.Here is my apex code.
Pdf file contains 'County' text but it doesn't goes into if loop.

```
list<Attachment> aa = [select id,Name,Body from Attachment where Parentid='a1jK000000089qR'];
string str = 'County';
try{
for(Attachment a: aa){
string strbody = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(a.body);
//   string strbody = (a.body).toString();
 system.debug('------strbody-1----'+strbody);

if(strbody.containsIgnoreCase(str))
 {
   system.debug('------true-----');
   system.debug('------name-----'+a.Name);
   }
 } 
}
catch(Exception e){
 system.debug('------exception-----'+e);  
}
```

Comment: any spelling mistakes? `County` or `Country` ?

Comment: no spelling mistakes..If you change String str = 'Any text from pdf'  ... it is not going into if loop

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code:

```
Blob b = Page.PAGENAME.getContentAsPdf();
String s = b.toString();
```

This will raise the following exception: `System.StringException: BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string`.

A PDF consists of binary data, it is therefore not possible to do a reliable search in a PDF attachment.

Encoding the Blob to Base64 won't help either, since the result contains in no way the original content.

Your best bet would be, attaching plain text and searching its content.

Answer (score 1):

When base64 encoding is done, individual bytes do not map to a single encoded character. So the base 64 you get for an ASCII "County" will be different depending on what precedes that text in the PDF. See the "Example" section of this [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

So I'm afraid the string matching approach you are trying won't work in general (even if you also base 64 encode the search string).